# Phonegap build problems

Tags: xcode, ipad, cordova

i have recently created my first app and got it onto my ipad, however, i wasn't getting the "phonegap is working" alert. After digging around the code, it seems the onDeviceReady function is not running and i narrowed it down to the phonegap-1.3.0.js, which was missing. I thought that phonegap build this file automatically, but can't seem to find it anywhere. can someone tell me hoe to generate this file or where i can download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that you have all the phonegap files that you need, and download the zip file from here: http://phonegap.com/download-thankyou (assuming you're ok with using the latest PhoneGap).

Comment: I updated to the latest build earlier today, but still the same issue

Comment: Yep '<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>'

Comment: If you're using the latest code, you need to link to the newest file name, which is "cordova-1.5.0.js"

Comment: oh ok, where do i find this file, as it's not getting built

Comment: Once you download and unzip the file (from the link), you can look under lib/android/cordova-1.5.0.js for the Javascript file. It should be the same for all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Visit http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/source/browse/trunk/com.mds.apg/resources/phonegap/js/phonegap-1.3.0.js?r=126

Comment: perfect, exactly what i was looking for!